# Why Math.max(array int[]) returns NAN with typescript even though all are integers?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I am generating an array of int with the following code,

```
  this.values = new Array(3).fill(0).map((v, i) => i + 1);
```

and then when i do,

```
 this.quantity = Math.max(this.values);
```

it returns NAN. what is the issue? when i put a console.log(this.values), i can see interger array with [1,2,3] as values.

Comment: You have to spread the values, `Math.max` takes a variable number of arguments, not an array. Since you pass in an array, not a number, the result is NaN because the function applies `ToNumber` on all the arguments and NaN is the result of an array being coerced to a number. `Math.max(...this.values)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Math.max`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) does not take an array, it takes multiple arguments. (Your array is cast to a number, which leads to `NaN` since `"1,2,3"` is not a number).

You can use [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) for the call:

```
this.quantity = Math.max(...this.values);
```

Answer (score -1):

The function `Math.max()` does not work like that. It takes two (or more) integers and then returns the greater one. For example:

`Math.max(3, 1, 2); // returns 3`

Comment: Nope. It takes a varying number of arguments. Try `Math.max(3, 4, 2, 44, 3)`.

Comment: The Math.max() function returns the largest **of zero or more numbers.**

Comment: This does not provide a solution to when you have an array you want to process.

Answer (score -2):

Math.max does not take an array, try this

```
Math.max.apply(Math, this.values);
```

Comment: This answer does not explain very well *why* it works. It only explains why the code in the question **does not** work.